# django: display selected choices in MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django

I have to address a ticket of code someone else wrote.

The form:

```
class MultiForm(forms.Form):
  agencies = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
     choices = AGENCY_TYPE,
     widget = CheckboxSelectMultipleNoLi,
     required=False)
```

This all works fine.

I can display the form easily:

```
form = MultiForm()
```

However, I can't see the the checked elements on the form.
The data is in a dedicated table:

```
 Agency.objects.filter(application=application)
```

That's just referring to a table:

```
 note | application_id |   type    |  id  
------+----------------+-----------+------
```

where all checked elements will have an entry and their value will be `type`.
(in other words all Agency elements of an application will have a row).

So when the data is created, it's in a registration form, thus it doesn't get displayed again, it's just one time when the user registers.

How can I display the checked elements (I am showing the form in another part of the app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post put me on track to find the solution:

[Set initial value of checkbox dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914488/set-initial-value-of-checkbox-dynamically)

```
 data = Agency.objects.filter(application=application)
      selected = []
      for a in data:
        selected.append(a.type)
      form = MultiForm(initial={'agencies':selected})
```