# How to link checkbox value to a model's attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

The idea is to have something like this:

`template.html`

```
{% for item in items %}
    <input type="checkbox" checked= {{ item.status }}>
{% endfor %}
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
    context = { 'items' : Item.objects.all() }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

But the `status` by design isn't simply `True` or `False`:

`models.py`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        ON = 1
        OFF = 0
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status.choices)
    # other attributes..
```

How will I link these two values so that they're two-way connected? (Loading `template.html` yields the checkbox's checked-ness based on the retrieved `item.status` (checked for `ON`, unchecked for `OFF`, while checking or unchecking the checkboxes will change the related `item.status` value?)

The only thing I've seen closest to my problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914488/set-initial-value-of-checkbox-dynamically#15914594), but it's not the same at all. Mine is a single binary attribute but has different kinds of values.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a BooleanField instead, if the status is either on or off.

Comment: a `ModelForm` with a `ChoicesField` is the way to go

Comment: nope, I really needed it as such. This is just a simplification

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems that your status should be a BooleanField... But let's assume you really need those choices.

You need to tell your form to use a CheckboxInput instead of a Select.
You need to tell the widget which value should check the widget.
You need to convert the returned boolean as an Iteam.Status attribute.

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('status',)
        widgets = {
            'status': forms.CheckboxInput(
                check_test=lambda status: status == Item.Status.ON,
            ),
        }

    def clean_status(self):
        return (
            Item.Status.ON if self.cleaned_data.get('status')
            else Item.Status.OFF
        )
```

Here are the part of the doc you need:

- [Override default fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)
- [CheckboxInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#selector-and-checkbox-widgets)
- [Cleaning specific field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

Comment: How would you load the initial value of the attribute of the item to the checkbox? Since the `context` in `index` in `views` is now passed as `{'items': Item.objects.all(), 'form': Form()}`